# In MonoTouch, is it possible to mix standard Views and iPhoneOSGameViews?

Tags: opengl-es, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to have like a main menu based on a let's say a `DialogViewController`, and navigate to a OpenGL-ES based iPhoneOSGameView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can even add multiple OpenGL ES views as subviews of a standard UIView.

Though you ask about iPhoneOSGameView specifically, I recommend considering [**GLKView**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKView_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) available as of iOS 5. This provides some of the same features as the iPhoneOSGameView as well as some of the generated boilerplate around animation and CADisplayLink.  It would also give you the option of creating the view in the Interface Builder, should you desire.  Finally, it is provided by Apple to fill a similar role and, arguably, would be more aligned with future development.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the reverse.  In fact, [MonoGame](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame) supports opening `iPhoneOSGameView` as the main view and displaying standard modal view controllers over top of it.  This functionality is in the GamerServices section of XNA.

I think you should create a simple example, print a solid color in the game view and try presenting it over top of a standard controller.

I would think it would work fine.